# Click button onclick event selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying to automate a webpage to upload some data and there is a button which has HTML like that

```
<input type="file" class="upfile" name="upfile" id="upfile" style="height:auto;width:250px;" onclick="hideWarning(upfileWarning);hideWarning(pdfWarning);hideWarning(sizeWarning);">
```

When I tried this line

```
.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('upfile').click();"
```

It didn't trigger the dialog box that is supposed to be populated. Any ideas?

Comment: you can use sendKeys() on the <input type="file" element.  Send the file's path.  It'll set the 'value' accordingly.

Comment: Website link please? Or is it behind a login?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a website that needs credentials. I found the line is working after restarting the code `.ExecuteScript "document.getElementById('upfile').click();"`